# Passing java object to BIRT Report

Tags: export, report, birt

I have a requirement in BIRT report.

Currently I have HTML table. It has list of values. I need to generate the report using BIRT. Export all the HTML data in to excel format. I need to generate the report using BIRT.

I am sending the list of rows as list object and send to server side. How can i iterate the data and generate the report using BIRT? Can i send this list of object in to one parameter and send to BIRT report? Can any one help this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Java Objects (POJO’s) as datasource. Please see [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseBIRT/article.html#datasource-and-dataset) tutorial